# Can we change the user agent to run outlook addin in Edge instead of IE in Outlook

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Can we change the user agent to run outlook addin in Edge instead of IE in Outlook.

I am using windows 10 less than 1900 build?

If build is >1903 it is taking Edge otherwise taking as IE.

Is there any way to update the user agent?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to configure Outlook to run an add-in Edge instead of IE without upgrading to the correct Windows + Outlook + Browser configuration. We have documentation on this here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins